# Obtener valor concreto de un DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Tengo un datagrid con el siguiente código:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="order_grid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="True" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding Path=name}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding Path=price}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" IsReadOnly="true" Binding="{Binding Path=amount}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Y le añado filas así:

```
var data = new Product { name = variableName, price = variablePrice, amount = variableAmount };
            order_grid.Items.Add(data);
```

Quiero saber si puedo coger el valor de una celda determinada apartir de el valor de otra columna. Es decir, en el datagrid tengo las columnas: Name|Price|Amount, puedo obtener el valor de amount de un Name en concreto? sin tener que seleccionar la fila

Comment: Si, pero si quieres obtener datos específicos tienes que poder diferenciar las filas, es decir, con un "ID", ya que el "Name" podría repetirse, luego simplemente haces un FOR a "order_grid.Items", que los puedes ir casteando a "Product" y vas chequeando cual elemento coincide con el ID (o name) que estás buscando, el que coincida lo tomas y como ya sabes que es un objeto de tipo "Product" simplemente llamas a su propiedad ( (Product) p).Amount

No tiene mayor ciencia que eso, simplemente ten en cuenta que cada fila es un "Product", no una "fila" y se te hará muy fácil..

Comment: gracias voy a probar en un rato a ver

Comment: No hay problema, si se te complica entender la idea, dilo y te pongo una respuesta completa con código.

Comment: Si por favor si puede ponerlo un poco más completo con código se lo agradecería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siguiendo con el comentario que escribí, acá el truco sería obtener el dato sin tener que seleccionar la fila, es decir, hacerlo mediante código.

Para eso tendrías que crear un método que reciba el Name que quieres, que sería escrito en un TextBox o algo así, ya que no quieres seleccionar la fila y que entonces obtenga el Amount, pero el Amount podrías obtenerlo de muchas formas.

1)
En este ejemplo obtengo todo el objeto Product coincidente, pero solo el primero, si hay más objetos con el mismo Name tendrías que hacerlo de la manera que muestro más abajo.

```
public void ObtenerAmount(string _name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < order_grid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((Product)order_grid.Items[i]).Name.Equals(_name))
        {
            Product p = (Product)order_grid.Items[i];
            //p es el producto que buscas (p.Amount)
            //puedes usarlo acá directamente 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Así sería para retornar todos los coincidentes:

```
public void ObtenerUnDato(string _name)
{
    List<Product> temp = new List<Product>();
    for (int i = 0; i < order_grid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((Product)order_grid.Items[i]).Name.Equals(_name))
        {
            temp.Add((Product)order_grid.Items[i]);
        }
    }

    //si quieres retornar esa lista cambia VOID por List<Product> 
    //y en esta linea pones retun temp;
}
```

2)
Retornando SOLO el Amount para usarlo en otro método.

```
public int ObtenerAmount(string _name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < order_grid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((Product)order_grid.Items[i]).Name.Equals(_name))
        {
            return ((Product)order_grid.Items[i]).Amount;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

3)
Retornar TODO el objeto que coincida (solo el primero):

```
public Product ObtenerUnDato3(string _name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < order_grid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (((Product)order_grid.Items[i]).Name.Equals(_name))
        {
            return (Product)order_grid.Items[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Como la pregunta es un poco ambigua te dejo todas estas posibles soluciones para que veas cuál se adapta mejor a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Genial, con el primero me valdría porque no se repiten los Name, mil gracias